# How does this function compute the distance from line start to the intersection?

Tags: javascript, math, glsl, shader, webgl

I have this code in GLSL which looks like this:

```
float Intersect(vec2 lineOneStart, vec2 lineOneEnd, vec2 lineTwoStart, vec2 lineTwoEnd) {
  vec2 line2Perp = vec2(lineTwoEnd.y - lineTwoStart.y, lineTwoStart.x - lineTwoEnd.x);
  float line1Proj = dot(lineOneEnd - lineOneStart, line2Perp);

  if (abs(line1Proj) < 0.0001) {
    return 0.;
  }

   return dot(lineTwoStart - lineOneStart, line2Perp) / line1Proj;
}
```

I have drawn up a visualization of what I *think* this coding is doing, in the following illustration:

[image]

Hopefully that image is correct, if not please let me know.

Basically, I am trying to write a function that, given two line segments, returns the distance from `lineOneStart` to the intersection point in `lineTwo`. In reality, lineOne extends forever in its direction, but for simplicity I just gave it a very long length such that it will always reach `lineTwo`.

I obtained this code from elsewhere, but the problem is I don't understand *how* it works, or even if it is working. I obtained the code from the demo posted at the bottom of [this article](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RobWare/20180226/313491/Fast_2D_shadows_in_Unity_using_1D_shadow_mapping.php)

In the article, the author describes the code as the following:

> ...Compute the intersection point between and the line segment and the light ray at the current angle, but this is just a couple of dot products and a divide, so nothing too heavy for a modern GPU.

But it doesn't really seem to be doing that? In that the first line of the function seems to make the line go to the start of `lineTwo`, rather than along its angle to the closest intersection point.

In addition, the dot product has always been mystifying to me, so I'm having trouble seeing how two dot products here is giving me the claimed result. Is this code correct, and if so, how does it work?

Comment: No, although I suppose there isn't really any Javascript here. In reality I am coding in WebGL and calling this shader from Javascript, but that's likely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

If you've a endless line which is defined by a point `P` and a normalized direction `R` and a second endless line, which is defined by a point `Q` and a direction `S`, then the intersection point of the endless lines `X` is:

[image]

```non
alpha ... angle between Q-P and R
beta  ... angle between R and S

gamma  =  180° - alpha - beta

h  =  | Q - P | * sin(alpha)
u  =  h / sin(beta)

t  = | Q - P | * sin(gamma) / sin(beta)

t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, S)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))
u  =  dot(Q-P, (R.y, -R.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, R)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))

X  =  P + R * t  =  Q + S * u
```

In general The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

[image]

---

In your case `line2Perp` is `(S.y, -S.x)`:

```c
 vec2 line2Perp = vec2(lineTwoEnd.y - lineTwoStart.y, lineTwoStart.x - lineTwoEnd.x);
```

`line1Proj` is `dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))`:

```c
float line1Proj = dot(lineOneEnd - lineOneStart, line2Perp);
```

and `lineTwoStart - lineOneStart` is `Q-P`:

```c
return dot(lineTwoStart - lineOneStart, line2Perp) / line1Proj;
```